# SQL Server : why does Bulk Load fail?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Bulk Load fails when I uncomment the rownum line with the following errors. I know the workaround for this issue. But I need to understand why does it show error message.

> Msg 4866, Level 16, State 1, Line 41
>   The bulk load failed. The column is too long in the data file for row 1, column 1. Verify that the field terminator and row terminator are specified correctly.
>
> Msg 7399, Level 16, State 1, Line 41
>   The OLE DB provider "BULK" for linked server "(null)" reported an error. The provider did not give any information about the error.
>
> Msg 7330, Level 16, State 2, Line 41
>   Cannot fetch a row from OLE DB provider "BULK" for linked server "(null)".

Code:

```
CREATE TABLE #TEMPFILE
(
    LINE VARCHAR(5000)
    ,rownum int identity(1,1) primary key
)

EXEC('BULK INSERT #TEMPFILE FROM '''+ @FILENAME + ''' WITH (ROWTERMINATOR = ''0x0a'', lastrow = 1)  ')
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the syntax i have used for bulk insert in SQL Server

```
BULK
INSERT Table_Name
FROM FileName/FilePath
WITH
(
  FIRSTROW = 2,
  FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
  ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
)
```

Comment: I'm aware of the workaround, but is there a limitation if a row cannot store certain amount of data?

Comment: @Priyesh Yeah, if the data is longer than the specified field. Could be you havent specified a field terminator too

Comment: @Priyesh whats an example of the data you're trying to insert?

Comment: What I was trying to achieve was to insert any delimiter file data of row terminator = '\n' into the line column of #tempfile table and have another column as an identity column for querying purpose. Surprisingly bulk insert with keep identity option doesn't work too. So I had to manually add the column exclusively after insertion.